# Universal Link not opening app on iOS. How to pinpoint the issue?

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios, ios-universal-links

I am trying to implement Universal Links in my app using Xamarin.iOS but it is not working. I have already completed the following steps.

1. I have uploaded apple-app-site association file on the m.mydomain.com server in the .well-known directory and it is being validated by the apple app search validation tool. I have used the paths **["*", "/"]** and verified the team id and bundle id.
2. I have enable associated domains in the provisioning profile.
3. I have added `applinks:m.mydomain.com` as an associated domain.
4. I have implemented the following methods: ContinueUserActivity, WillContinueUserActivity, UserActivityUpdated, OpenURL

Even after these steps, the app never opens, instead a webpage opens.

I am using Xamarin.Forms 4.7 and iOS 15.6 (simulator) & 16 (device)

Apple App Site Association File:

```
{
"applinks": {
    "apps": [],
    "details": [
        {
            "appID": "<AppId>",
            "paths": ["*", "/"]
        },
        {
            "appID": "<AppId>",
            "paths": ["*", "/"]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please post relevant apple-app-site-association file (be sure to hide the appIDs).

Comment: @JavierRefuerzo I have added the file contents

Answer (score 0):

See: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html

I think you need to change

```
"paths": ["*", "/"]
```

to

```
"paths": ["*"]
```

While the above is how it is described in the docs I think the following pattern is better for multiple apps.

```
{
  "applinks": {
      "details": [
           {
             "appIDs": [ "<appId_app_one>"],
             "comment": "This is for the APP_ONE_NAME iOS App. Based on https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/649423 for multiple apps",
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/expert/abc",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /expert/abc"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/expert/xyz",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /expert/xyx"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/pwdreset/dret",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /pwdreset/dret"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/emailverification/dret",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /emailverification/dret"
               }
             ]
           },
           {
             "appIDs": [ "<appId_app_two>"],
             "comment": "This is for the APP_TWO_NAME iOS App",
             "components": [
               {
                  "#": "no_universal_links",
                  "exclude": true,
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose fragment equals no_universal_links and instructs the system not to open it as a universal link"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/pwdreset/mobile",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /pwdreset/mobile"
               },
               {
                  "/": "/emailverification/mobile",
                  "comment": "Matches any URL whose path starts with /emailverification/mobile"
               }
             ]
           }
       ]
   }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this format, it still does not work.

Comment: Looks like there may be issues on iOS 16+.  Did it also fail on 15?